# Backup name in Maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, maintenance-plans

I used to have SQL Server 2005 installed on my server. In my maintenance plan, the backup name format was like this: `mydatabase_backup_yyyymmddhhss.bak`.

Now I am using SQL Server 2012 but I am getting a totally different backup name format. I would like to have the same format name as 2005.

How can I do this?

Comment: When you take backup from SQL server 2012 maintenance plan your backup file name will be like this mydatabase_backup_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_ss.bak right

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build a custom backup script which uses dynamic SQL to build the name of the .bak file. The maintenance plan could execute this with the 'Execute T-SQL Statement Task' item.

The T-SQL would look something like this

```
Select @SQL = 'BACKUP DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] TO  DISK = N''' + @Path + '\' + @DBName + '_backup_' + @Date + '.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N''' + @DBName + '_backup_' + @Date + ''', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10 '

EXEC SP_ExecuteSql @SQLToExecute = @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script to get DB backup as per your format. This can be scheduled with SQL Agent Job

```
DECLARE @FOLDERPATH VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @FOLDERPATHWITHNAME VARCHAR(500)
Declare @NAME Varchar(200)
Declare @DATE Varchar(200)
Declare @TIME Varchar(200)
Declare @TIME1 Varchar(200)

-------------------------------------------------------    
--JUST NEED TO UPDATE BELOW PATH FOR DB BACKUP LOCATION
-------------------------------------------------------

Set @FOLDERPATH = 'D:\Temp\Dsingh\'

select @TIME1 = Convert(time, getdate())

select @DATE = (select convert(varchar,getDate(),112))

select @TIME = ((select Convert(Varchar, DATEPART(hh, @TIME1))) 
               + (Select CONVERT(Varchar, DATEPART(ss, @TIME1))))

Select @NAME = 'mydatabase_backup' + '_' + @DATE + @TIME

Set @FOLDERPATHWITHNAME = @FOLDERPATH + @NAME + '.bak'

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @FOLDERPATH

BACKUP DATABASE [TEST_1_Smarttrack_03202014] 
       TO  DISK = @FOLDERPATHWITHNAME WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
       NAME = @NAME, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```